# Suppress Chapter Number in Report Class

Tags: numbering, chapters, report

I am using the `report` class (to write my PhD thesis). Basically, I have an introduction and then list my publications; I want each of these to be their own chapter. However, because they are pretty disjoint, I don't want to bother having the chapter number referenced all the time. Eg `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` using `amsthm` gives a theorem environment which is numbered by section. This is ideal in my separate publications: `Theorem 2.3`, `Theorem 3.1`, etc. However, now they come up as `Theorem 1.2.3` (if in `Chapter 1`) or `Theorem 2.3.1` (if in `Chapter 2`).

Similarly, anything else that you can think of should not include the chapter number. Basically, if you were to look at a page in the bulk of the one of 'subpapers', one should not be able to tell from the numbering that it is part of, say, `Chapter 3`.

Is there some way of getting rid of the `\thechapter.` part from everything automatically? I could go through all my things (`thm`, `section`, `subsection`, etc) -- in fact, I have done this -- but I'd rather have an automated version.

Additionally, some of the individual papers have appendices. So I'd like to be able to use `\appendix` to swap to `A`, `B`, ... -- but this shouldn't come up as `1.A`, ...

I would also like to be able to change `\thechapter` to be maybe alphabetic or maybe Roman, so the solution should be compatible with this.

Comment: How should equations be numbered in a chapter? As (1), (2), etc, or should they be prefixed by the section number? Should equation numbers restart with each new chapter?

Comment: Good point. Similarly, anything else that you can think of should not include the chapter number. Basically, if you were to look at a page in the bulk of the one of 'subpapers', one should not be able to tell from the numbering that it is part of, say, `Chapter 3`. So this applies for equations, sections, theorems and anything else you can imagine!

Comment: Your desired setup is actually thoroughly problematic: The full document may feature multiple sections numbered `1` etc, multiple theorems numbered `1` etc, multiple equations numbered `(1)`, etc. Your readers will likely become thoroughly confused when they come across several instances to distinct equations all numbered "(1)".

Comment: Due to the _extremely_ modular nature of the thesis, I feel that this won't be an issue. For example, one part is on stochastic networks, while another is on random walks on a torus; yet another is on random walks on random Cayley graphs. I don't know what subject you're into (or maybe not academic at all, just love tex!). But these are very different, and I feel that there won't be confusion `:)`

Comment: The comments so far appear to have the implicit assumption that you may have cross references to equations in another chapter.  If you have *no* such cross references, you'll probably be okay.  But as soon as you add even one, you'll have a problem avoiding confusion.

Comment: I expect to have no cross reference, or maybe just a couple in the introduction. I can then always just post/prefix "in `Chapter #`". But yes, I shall be careful! :)

Comment: If i understand your setup correctly, each individual unnumbered chapter already exists as a standalone pdf file. If this interpretation is correct, you'd be much better off creating a controller document that "includes" the individual documents with the help of the [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package. (If you care about pages being numbered consecutively, all you'd have to do is to increment the `page` counter suitably in latex driver files and recompile them.) Please advise if my intuition is correct.

Comment: That certainly is an option! Although I would change them a little. Eg I would like the option of a final (combined) bibliography. (I know about `refsection` from `biblatex` gives the option for a bibliography for different sections.) I'd probably want one big `tableofcontents` too. (The idea of being able to have separate tables of contents _as well_ is nice though!) \\ I'm guessing that the original question isn't as easy as I thought it might be?

Comment: After discussing with my supervisor, we decided that my thesis would be too long with the different papers. So I'm just taking one project. (Should've asked her before I started doing the combining, but hey ho!) As such, this question is no longer _needed_ for me. However, I've left it open as it is an interesting concept which may be helpful for others in the future